Superexponential decay of a function and its Fourier transform
Suppose that $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ is such that both $f$ and its Fourier transform $\hat{f}(\xi)=\int e^{-2\pi i \xi x}f(x)dx$ are entire functions whose restrictions to each slice of constant imaginary part are also in $L^2$. Then by the Paley-Wiener argument, both $f$ and $\hat{f}$ should decay faster than any exponential as $x$ goes to $\pm\infty$ on the real axis.
Now suppose we also know that both $f$ and $\hat{f}$ are not only in $L^2$ on the slices, but decay faster than any exponential as $Re(z)$ (resp. $Re(\xi)$) goes to $\pm\infty$ along horizontal lines in the lower half plane, with $f$ decaying faster than any exponential as $Re(z)$ goes to $-\infty$  along the slices in the upper half plane, and $\hat{f}$ decaying faster than any exponential as $\Re(\xi)\rightarrow\infty$ along these slices.  Is it necessarily true that $f$ also decays faster than any exponential as $Re(z)$ goes to $+\infty$ along the slices in the upper half plane? If not, does anyone know a counterexample?
